# Issues caused by the update to 16.10

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, ubuntu-gnome, 16.10

I've just updated my ubuntu from 16.04 to .10.
Unfortunately, on one hand using the Xorg with gnome no more supports multi-touch as it did (using a touch-screen), and, on the other, on Wayland this weird window frame shows up.

[image: weird window]

Any idea on how to solve this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I did not find any one else with this problem but possibly because I didn't search with the most suitable keywords (hopefully I did).

Comment: The "weird frame" looks like a terminal window. What happens when you type "exit" and press Enter?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, the weird frame disappears when I remove the transparency.

Comment: Oh I'm so dumb, you meant the border around the terminal window when you said "frame". I guess the developers thought transparency didn't highlight the window well enough so they added a very thick border (ie frame) around the window. Can you write your answer so others know the problem is solved?